# Vuetable-2 field formatter not working as intended

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I am using vuetable-2 and somehow the formatter for my fields does not work. The frontend for my `isCoach` field still shows as `1` but based on the formatter set, it should instead return `Active`.

Template

```
<vuetable
  ref="vuetable"
  api-url=""
  :query-params="makeQueryParams"
  :per-page="perPage"
  pagination-path
  data-path="Data"
  :reactive-api-url="true"
  :fields="fields"
  :row-class="onRowClass"
  @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
  @vuetable:cell-rightclicked="rightClicked"
>
```

Data

```
fields:[
{
          name: "isCoach",
          sortField: "isCoach",
          title: "Coach",
          titleClass: "",
          dataClass: "text-muted",
          width: "5%",
          formatter: (value) => {
            return value === '1' ? 'Active' : 'Disable'
          }
        },
]
```

Documentation: https://www.vuetable.com/guide/fields-definition.html#field-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently `formatter` doesn't work. Changing it to `callback` solved my issue.